# Merging lines with a given condition

Tags: regex, gedit

I have a file where there are contents in varying order . I would like to merge the lines which occur between two blank lines into a single line. Example:

> This
> was
> not
> good
>
> Can
> it
> be
> done
> like
> this

to

> This was not good
>
> Can it be done like this

[image]

Comment: Is this the actual file, or could there be more than one column? Right now, there's nothing to suggest it's a CSV file (since there are no commas)...

Comment: Treat it as a string and replace `(?<!\r?\n)\r?\n(?!\r?\n)` (any non-consecutive newline) with `" "` (a single space)

Comment: @TimPietzcker I have added a sample picture

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen . Its not working . It gives me an error saying 
"Error at character 9 , look behind assertion is not fixed length"

Comment: It would help to know the language/platform you're using

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen 
 
I just use it in gedit - on Debian 8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all the newlines that aren't followed by another newline with a space by searching for

```
\r?\n(?!\r?\n)
```

and replacing with `" "`.

Comment: This will also remove the extra newline between "This was not good" and "Can it be done like this" and will add a space at the beginning of every line after the first.

Comment: Out of curiosity :  Just in case there are two blank lines to be replaced ?

Comment: What do you mean? Two lines should be replaced, but not three?

Comment: Sorry , I got the answer . Thank you for the help @TimPietzcker

Answer (score 0):

Seems Gedit does not support `?` operator in lookbehind. This worked for me:

```
(?<!\n)\r?\n(?!\r?\n)
```